# PHP - MySQLi UPDATE +1 really adds 2

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to count page views on page load, although anytime I load the page 'UPDATE SET views = views + 1' is actually adding 2. I've got my code below, if any one has any suggestions that'd be awesome.

```
// Create database connection
$db = new mysqli($db[host], $db[user], $db[pass], $db[data]);

// Display database connection error (if applicable)
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}

// Define Visitor Variables
$visitor[ip] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);

// Checks database to see if ip exists in logs
$check[ip] = $db->query("SELECT ip FROM admin_views WHERE ip = '$visitor[ip]'");

// If ip is found in database, update page views counter if it's not found, create a record for it
if ($check[ip]->num_rows == 1){
    $db->query("UPDATE admin_views SET views = views +1 WHERE ip = '$visitor[ip]'");
} else {
    $db->query("INSERT INTO admin_views VALUES('NULL', '$visitor[ip]')");
    echo "not found";
}

// Count the number of views
$count_views = "SELECT SUM(views) AS countViews FROM admin_views";

if ($result = $db->query($count_views)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $views = $row['countViews'];
    }

    $result->free();
}

// Count unique page views
$count_unique_views = "SELECT id FROM admin_views ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

if ($result = $db->query($count_unique_views)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $unique_views = $row['id'];
    }

    $result->free();
}

// Close database connection
$db->close();
```

Comment: How do you know that it adds 2? If you base that on the result of the SUM that you think is happening exactly after you've done the update, you're probably wrong. Also, is there a unique index on the ip column?

Comment: Because when I refresh the table in phpMyAdmin I can clearly see it counted twice. No there is not a unique index on the ip column, would adding this make a differance?

Comment: Yes. Is your page publicly accessible?

Comment: I didn't mean it would fix it right away. So your code has severe issues, but I went too fast on thinking they were the root of your actual problem. It's not really the place here to discuss about it, but you should take care of the sql injection risk you have, and make sure of what happens when the same IP browses your page a second time before the first script is finished executing.

Comment: I understand that there's no protection against SQL injection. I'm only trying to learn. Thanks heaps for your help champ.

Comment: Are you sure your phpmyadmin query is reliable?

Comment: I cannot fathom why it wouldn't be. I'm using the UI, not a command line query.

Comment: Is it possible your script is actually being accessed twice? I had a similar script that was called as a handler for all requests that didn't exist as files. Some things like favicon.ico were being loaded and calling the script again. That might explain the second hit if this script is available via a modrewrite or something.